# .htaccess Rewrite: Internally have it be /mypage, but in the url look like /Home/mypage

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I probably have this completely wrong:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#Rewrites so it looks like production
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Home/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Home/$1 [L]
```

Can someone set me straight to make all urls http://site/somepage1 , http://site/somepage2, be rewritten as http://site/Home/somepage1, http://site/Home/somepage2.  Is there one rule that would capture all of those urls, and prepend '/Home' to all the urls?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Going into httpd.conf and setting 'LogLevel = debug' revealed that the two rules are conflicting:

```
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3065): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /Home/index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /Home/index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /Home/index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /Home/index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /Home/index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Sep 23 10:54:07 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /Home
```

Is there a way to combine these two rewrite rules without this redirection error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Home/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Home/$1 [L]
```

Obviously, if you request URL with `/Home/` in it directly (e.g. `http://site/Home/somepage1`, it will not be rewritten to `/Home/Home/somepage1` -- so keep this in mind in case you have  subfolder named the same as main folder.

---

**UPDATE:**
Considering new information, lets try this approach:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite incoming link to /Home/
# but only if it's a non-existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Home/|index\.php)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Home/$1 [L]

# route all requests for non-existing resources to /index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Using your example I get 500 error.  Here's my .htaccess file. I think my previous ReWriteRules are not playing nice, is there a way that they can both work?  Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#Rewrites so it looks like production
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Home/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Home/$1 [L]

Comment: 1) Put your current .htaccess into your question (edit it) as your  cannot be formatted nicely in comments (as you can see). 2) Check Apache's error log for **exact** error message -- possibly 2 rules together causing infinite rewrite loop which Apache has to forcibly stop resulting in 500 error.

Comment: Updated the question with the full .htaccess rules, and added the apache errors I found. Is there a way to get these two rules working together?

Comment: Yes -- it's possible. But for that I need to know what URL is the correct one. For example, what will be the final URL for this request: `site.com/somepage1` ? In other words -- how to handle `/Home/` and `index.php` ?

Comment: Gotcha. I'd like site.com/somepage1 to be site.com/Home/somepage1. And site.com to be site.com/Home.

Comment: So ... what is `index.php` then ?? Where it is located -- in website root .. or `/Home/index.php` ? As you can clearly see these 2 rules interfere with each other. If `index.php` is in `/Home/index.php`, then just alter your first rule to use that path: `RewriteRule .* /Home/index.php [L]`. If it is not there -- then how do I need to process it? I'm confused as I do not know your website logic. For example: let's assume you have a logo file located at `/images/logo.png`. Does it needs to be rewritten to `/Home/images/logo.png` or ...?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking. index.php is in fact physically at the root '/'. However, I don't want it to show in the url anywhere. Regarding the images question, I would not want that path/url rewritten.

Comment: @program247365 Sorry for delay -- was away from my PC and Internet for a while (whole weekend). I hope I understood what you are trying to achieve -- see my updated answer. If it's still not what you want ... then you **really** have to explain it better.

Comment: No problem! You got it, that's it exactly. Sorry for the extended back-and-forth.